# White screen and crash - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, mapbox

I've been following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ok9v0YYgIG4 to begin with mapbox.
I've done everything the guy did in the vid, but when I launch the app on my device, I get a white screen and then the app crash (even if i have no error and no warning). Does anyone knows how to fix it and makes it work?

(for now, I just want to put a map on my screen)

here is the XML

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Mapview
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="6.641183"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="46.7784736"
        mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="12"
        />
```

and here is the code:

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView;
    private MapboxMap map;

    public MapActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, "pk.eyJ1IjoidGlyYWlubyIsImEiOiJja2F6Y3ZyejQwaWJ6MnJtaWdmcmU3cjV5In0.5_0xHC_VyQUgyvUQ8IVNfA");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
                mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS, new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {

                        // Map is set up and the style has loaded. Now you can add data or make other map adjustments.


                    }
                });
            }
        });

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        map = mapboxMap;
        enableLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

When I take a look at the debug, I got this:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testmapbox, PID: 25911
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testmapbox/com.example.testmapbox.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Mapview
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Mapview
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Mapview
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Mapview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.testmapbox-yBfjzQOu9Iwzqc3V9nJN9g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.testmapbox-yBfjzQOu9Iwzqc3V9nJN9g==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.testmapbox-yBfjzQOu9Iwzqc3V9nJN9g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:801)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:874)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.testmapbox.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)

Comment: You should not include your API key in the post.  You will probably want to generate a new one

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for the crash?

Comment: @MichaelKrussel I edited my post, I don't know if it's what you asked for.

Comment: So there error is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Mapview"`

Looks like the name is right, so it is some build configuration problem.  Might be R8 removing the class from the APK, but that seems unlikely, so I'm not sure what would be causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share both the project level build.gradle and the application build.gradle? The youtube video does not mention the configuration required in the project level build.gradle, so I assume this might be missing.

Please see this documentation on which dependencies are required: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/#1-add-the-dependency

Project level build.gradle, add this:

```js
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
```

Application level build.gradle, add this:

```js
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.2.0'
}
```

**Also, your code defines the onMapReady callback twice. You should get rid of one of them.**